# Options to build an interactive 3d sphere Android

Tags: android, 3d

I'm looking for options to build an interactive 3d sphere on Android.

I'm kind of new into native Android development so I am just exploring the ecosystem and investigating my alternatives to achieve this. I would like to have a texture on the sphere, rotate and zoom in and out.

For iOS, I achieved this using SceneKit which has a lot of things out of the box so was fairly simple.

For Android, I started using [Rajawali](https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali), but what I want to achieve doesn't seem as straightforward so far (probably because of my lack of experience though).

Before going any further, I wanted to get an opinion from Android devs and see if I have any other options that might make this a bit easier to build.

[Video of what I built in iOS](https://streamable.com/fyqkjm)